# After update, get "error: file not found." followed by "grub rescue> _"

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I just installed quite a lot of 12.10 updates, was prompted to reboot, and then found that I couldn't boot.

Comment: Since I'm not yet allowed to add comments since my low reputation I add the comment this way... I used 8128s Answer wit Boot-repair but I had to add this line before the apt-get update sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list like you see in the link he added to the answer

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use Boot Repair to fix your bootloader.

1. Boot Ubuntu from a LiveCD or Live USB
2. Connect to the internet
3. Open a terminal, and add the Boot Repair PPA

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`
4. Install Boot Repair

   `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`
5. Launch and use, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Using_Boot-Repair for more details

Comment: I had to run 3. as root (sudo su) instead of just sudoing

Comment: THANK YOU!! Saved my server after a power outage. Time to buy a UPS!

Comment: used with Kubuntu 13.10 and worked. Thanks.

Comment: Use `boot-repair -b` if you don't have any displays or just want to work on the terminal.

Answer (score 10):

1. Type `ls` to get a list of partitions
2. Enter `set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub` [you will almost certainly have to enter a different drive/partition in the brackets, you may just have to try all of those listed by `ls` until you find the one that works.
3. Type `insmod normal`
4. Type `normal` and you will get your boot prompt back!

See also: [The helpful place where I found this.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/355359/comments/4) I doubt this will work for everyone encountering this error, but I've put it here in the hope it helps someone.

Once you've loaded Ubuntu, run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` and `sudo update-grub` as soon as possible. This means you won't have to do that tedious process above every time you boot your machine.

Comment: when I run insmod normal it again says file not found

Comment: You can also use the command `ls (hd0,msdos1)/` to check the contents of the partition, which would be faster if you have many partitions.

Comment: This worked for me, except I have a separate boot partition, so the format was `set prefix=(hd0)/grub`, since you need to reference the `grub` directory relative to the partition on the drive, not relative to its mount point during normal operation.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue - `normal.mod not found`, `ls` of the boot partition would produce a blank line. After a week of troubleshooting to get the system to boot properly here are the steps I went through.

1. Got a copy of [SuperGrub](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) and created a boot cd.  I could now get logged back on to my system.  Got a copy of [BootRepair](https://launchpad.net/boot-repair) and had not luck getting the system to boot directly from the hard disk and had to keep using the CD.  BootRepair did act a little strange since the Grub location and Grub options were grayed out.  It did report a successful install.
2. Hard drive was originally set up:
       `sda1 ext4 root with boot`
       `sda2 linux swap`
       `sda3 ext4 used as a spare drive` (holds VMs for Virtual box).
3. Used a copy of Ubuntu 10.10 live cd.  Ran [gparted [image: Install gparted]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted) to shrink the `sda1` partition and created `sda4` ext4 boot partition at the front of the drive and set mount point to `/boot` after deleting the boot directory from `/`.   BootRepair now has options available. Installed on boot partition and can now boot from hard drive.
4. Being curious I decided to investigate further.  The boot repair log had a peculiar entry for my `sda1` ext4 partition, it was reported as `DOS` and had a short 8 character UUID instead of the UUID reported by blkid.  `grub-probe` reported the file system as vfat.
5. After many other trials I cleared the first 440 bytes of `sda1` partition record.  `Grub-probe` now reports file system as ext2.  Ran `update-grub` and the correct UUID for the `sda1` partition appears.

The issue seems to be two-fold:
1. It seem to affect installations where the partition record has references to msdos.
2. `grub-probe` does not try to resolve mismatch issues between fs type and contents in the partition record.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to check is the boot order in your BIOS. I apparently had installed grub installed on all my disks (perhaps after following 8128's answer), but this broke when updating my Linux distro (Debian). Changing the first boot disk as my Linux OS fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this error upgrading to Kubuntu 13.10.   I had a memory stick plugged into the USB port during the dist-upgrade.  After rebooting I went straight to Grub Rescue.  Unplugging the USB drive and rebooting fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had downgraded to  GRUBv1 and after the upgrade to 12.10 grub2 couldn't find his files (*.mod, etc...), although the grub.cfg was there.

I found a more comprehensive manual on grub rescue:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting#grub_rescue.3E-1

See also the command list at the begining of the page.
Thx flute flute.