# Error while Booting Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, 14.04, error-handling

Recently I upgraded to Ubuntu14.04, whenever Boot loader starts, Getting an error message `Error : file not found` for 3 seconds and OS starts loading, While Loading OS also getting same error Message:

```
Error : file not found 
Error : file not found 
Error : file not found 

Press Any Key to Continue
```

until unless i press the key the OS is not loading.

Please provide me a solution to avoid those error messages.

Comment: Did you look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/187862/after-update-get-error-file-not-found-followed-by-grub-rescue ?

Comment: I have the same problem after upgrading to 14.04 from 12.04. I've found a comment that could be useful: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?63221-Grub-errors-quot-File-Not-Found-quot-repeated-three-times I have a laptop with ubuntu as the only OS and a non-UEFI bios. If anyone solves it, please, post the solution.
Thanks,

Answer (score 14):

First, for what is discussed in forums and in Launchpad just try:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX

sudo update-grub

sudo reboot
```

And there is a useful comment in Kubuntu's forum:

[www.kubuntuforums.net](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?63221-Grub-errors-quot-File-Not-Found-quot-repeated-three-times)

I have the same issue with a laptop with ubuntu as the only operating system with a non-UEFI bios.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This worked for me. Just wanna clarify since the OP did not give a check mark.