# Can not boot anymore after a boot repair

Tags: 14.04, boot, boot-repair, toshiba-satellite, toshiba

I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 on my Toshiba satellite z930. Ubuntu is the only OS on this computer (windows 8 was wiped right away).

Everything went great, except that the following message appeared:

> Error : file not found
>
> Error : file not found
>
> Error : file not found
>
> Press Any Key to Continue'

After pressing any key, I could indeed load ubuntu normally.

I decided to fix this issue, came across [Error while Booting Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460908/error-while-booting-ubuntu-14-04) . The solution proposed did not work, so I searched further and found (I don't know where) the advise to run Boot Repair. Since then, I get the following message when I try to start my computer:

> Insert system disk in drive.
>
> Press any key when ready....

The last report I got from Boot Repair can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10603340/ .

So , in short, things went almost perfect before running boot repair. Now, they do not work at all.

What can I do next ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After digging around and experimenting, I am glad to share the solution that worked for me (i.e. a complete beginner in the field). As far as I understood, my Toshiba Satellite Z930 will ONLY boot windows from UEFI.

Here is exactly what I did, (and so can any newbie, trust me):

- I downloaded boot-repair-disk (sorry I can't post the link, this is because of the restriction to 2 posted links per post for unexperienced users, but just ask Dr. Google)
- I made a bootable USB with the help of UNetBootIn (again, no link)
- I booted from the USB
- Once the lubuntu interface was loaded, I pressed Ctrl-Alt-F1 to open a shell, and typed the following:

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
  ```
- After checking the content of my directory with the ls command, I found out that /EFI/Boot was already there. So I made a backup of bootx64.efi by typing

  ```
  sudo mv /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.backup
  ```
- Then I copied all the content of the /mnt/EFI/ubuntu into /mnt/EFI/Boot with the following command line:

  ```
  sudo cp /mnt/EFI/ubuntu/* /mnt/EFI/Boot
  ```
- Finally, I renamed the file grubx64.efi to bootx64.efi by typing

  ```
  sudo mv /mnt/EFI/Boot/grubx64.efi /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
  ```

The last step was to open a bottle of champagne to celebrate. But I guess you don't have to. Instead, you can just thank warmly **[oldfred](https://askubuntu.com/users/126395/oldfred)** for all the time he took to post his solutions.

The solution is based on the following threads external to Ask Ubuntu:

Although the full answer was here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147295 in the subsection "Systems that only boot Windows from UEFI", I found easier to follow the explanations from this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2247186 .