# Can't set uefi boot order. Faulty firmware?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, gpt

I am trying to change boot order on my UEFI GPT system (because of preinstalled Windows 8.1) on my HP Envy 15.

Successfully installed ubuntu alongside windows. Boot-repair said it successfully did the job (default boot ubuntu (grub)) but it still auto boots to Windows.

I tried command `efibootmgr` which seemingly did job, but after restart it was still the same

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,3001,0002,0003,0006,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Notebook Hard Drive   BIOS(2,500,00)................-.U.......U.A.U............................................A.........................
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,c8800,82000,da584079-a49f-42a6-ab07-612e1667dd3f)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(3,14a800,82000,a49435dc-57eb-4974-8b37-87f1f0a073dd)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(3,14a800,82000,a49435dc-57eb-4974-8b37-87f1f0a073dd)File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0006* ubuntu    HD(2,c8800,82000,da584079-a49f-42a6-ab07-612e1667dd3f)File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)  RC
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
Boot3002* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
Boot3003* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
```

setting the order

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -o 0006,0001,0000
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0006,0001,0000
Boot0000* Notebook Hard Drive
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0003* ubuntu
Boot0006* ubuntu
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3002* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3003* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
```

after restart it's the same as in the beginning.

I even tried to setup in Windows 8.1

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

but it returned error something like "can't access drive", even though I manually mounted ESM partition. The same error using EasyBCD utility...

My "BIOS" can't select boot partition, just drive...

Any experience with laptop firmware upgrade?

Comment: Someone with a new HP did say there was a convoluted way to add a valid UEFI entry. But most HP seem to have modified UEFI to use  "Windows" description. That is not UEFI standard.  You may see versions where grub is copied over Windows bootgfw.efi but then a Windows update replaces it. Better to copy to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi and boot using hard drive entry. But on major grub update you may need to copy again. https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair  and/or: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  The problem of the efibootmgr boot order being reset at boot time is new.  This behavior just showed up on my Toshiba Satellite S855, which had been running fine for a year on 14.04, but after a Windows update 7/8, the boot order is reset each time at boot to a Windows-first default.