# Windows boots instead of asking which OS to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on my HP Compaq Laptop with UEFI, keeping my Windows installation.

I rebooted and was prompted if I wanted to boot Windows, Ubuntu or something like settings or more options.

I chose the last option and then chose to continue booting. The computer booted with Windows. I restarted the PC and it booted with Windows instead of prompting.

I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you do this: 1) press esc key while booting to access start up menu 2) press F9 for boot devices menu.  Many HP are hard coded to only boot "Windows" as they added description to UEFI. That is not per UEFI standard. Some work arounds: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789
Rename bootx64.efi
https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair

Comment: At the end of a ubuntu installation you get asked wether you want to install grub or not. What did you choose? Maybe you said no and therefore the boot menu is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Disable secure boot. It worked in my Pavilion x360. I did it before installing Ubuntu. But because Grub and Windows Boot partition issues I installed the Grub in my Ubuntu root partition.