# Windows boots instead of grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

help, I just installed linux but when I reboot, windows 10 starts instead of grub.
I try to selected a diffrent boot by pressing esc, but I could only chooice windows boot system, of my cd/dvd player.

secure boot is disabled (the answer of [Windows boots instead of asking which OS to boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648855/windows-boots-instead-of-asking-which-os-to-boot))

I am prety new to linux, So I hope somebody can help me with this?
It was already hard to install linux at the first place.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read the TROUBLESHOOTING
YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS

This is a common problem and if you do not get a GRUB menu , re-installing or repairing grub will NOT HELP " section

Answer (score 1):

Either you installed grub somewhere where your escape menu can't find it, or grub wasn't properly installed. Explore a bit in you BIOS boot settings, or try reinstalling linux and looking for grub options. Grub should be installed on your windows drive.

Comment: I saw that grub is installed in /boot/grub. I don' t know if this is the right location. Also, I can' t reinstall without removing all os (and I want to keep windows)

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi T"ROUBLESHOOTING
YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS

This is a common problem and if you do not get a GRUB menu , re-installing or repairing grub will NOT HELP"

Comment: reinstalling grub will not help as this is not a grub problem, it is a bios issue

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like grub is missing. Do something like this: 
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Or reinstall, and make sure you install grub on /dev/sda (assuming your drive is called sda, just DON'T install it on /dev/sda1 or something.
Look at the picture here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: Well, I see a folder nammed grub in /boot. and I can' t do a reinstall without removing windows (at least I think, there isn' t a option to reinstall. I can chooice to install next to all the systems, or remove everything).

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi T"ROUBLESHOOTING
YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS

This is a common problem and if you do not get a GRUB menu , re-installing or repairing grub will NOT HELP"

Comment: reinstalling grub will not help as this is not a grub problem, it is a bios issue