# Can't boot after boot-repair

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

This morning starts with ubuntu updates installation, which unfortunately freezes at some point. I hard-rebooted my laptop and got `grub>` command-line. There I tried manual boot from each of two latest linux images, but didn't succeed. I booted from USB stick instead and started boot-repair which succeeded. After reboot I got

```
Insert system disk in drive
Press any key when ready
```

Suspecting that something wrong with linux image I reboot with USB stick once again and run Boot Repair with option Purge linux images and install the latest one. Boot Repair hangs on exactly on this operation during the work. I mount my laptop's / and inspect that old images was purged but no one was installed. Then I chroot'ed to it and installed latest linux package manually through apt-get. Reboot, run Boot Repair once again (w/o purge option), it succeeds, reboot once again and got back `Insert system disk in drive` message. The report from last run of Boot Repair can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11958644/

Any suggestions what to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot-Repair allows to easily do the EFI renaming via the "Rename Windows EFI files" option, but that option is not enabled by default because it's a dirty hack and it is not reliable in all situations. Instead, it is safer to change the UEFI boot order, when possible, or have bcd call grub, which is what Boot-Repair suggests (see the 4 last lines of your log).

Comment: Thank you! I was sure for some reason that this option was turned on in BR, but it fails somehow.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
boot from a ubuntu installation live usb
```

and then

```
run boot-repair again
```

and use this

```
custom repair
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Thanks but manual hacking in /EFI worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe: exactly [the old dirty hack with manual renaming of EFI-files](https://askubuntu.com/a/597139/21445) works. I wonder why Boot Repair didn't manage this.