# Have to Boot Ubuntu 14 from within Windows 8.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I am a newbie to Ubuntu and not very knowledgeable about computers.  I have played around with Ubuntu on my HP Pavilion laptop a little bit with a bootable flash drive, and finally decided to take the jump and install so as to be able to Dual Boot.

I started up the flash drive, entered "try Ubuntu" mode and clicked on the desktop icon that says "Install Ubuntu".  I ran through the installation process it brought up without complications.  I did not create a seperate partition for the Ubuntu installer to overwrite, as I have since seen recommended.  Upon restarting the laptop without the bootable drive it booted directly into Windows.  I can still run Ubuntu, but I have to boot up through PC Settings> Recovery and Update> Recovery> Advanced Startup, at which point it lets me choose from three SSD options or a bootable disk.

I made sure that the Secure Boot option was turned off, and am not sure where to go from here.  If this involves uninstalling & reinstalling Ubuntu, I would appreciate a link to a walkthrough.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It is a feature of your BIOS. Look at your BIOS and see if there are any other options for boot order (varies by BIOS).

Comment: HP is not friendly to anything other than Windows. Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789
Rename bootx64.efi
https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair

Answer (score 0):

You need to install GRUB on the Windows drive:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda; sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

If that doesn't work, try the UEFI version of GRUB.

Comment: I typed the above into the terminal, but it didn't help.  I am trying to figure out how to add the UEFI version of GRUB.  Can anyone provide a link or the terminal commands?

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt-get install grub-efi`

Comment: Does that run successfully?

Comment: I had to move from Windows to Ubuntu, and now I can't find your subsequent posts with the terminal command.  Maybe commenting on your original again will bring them up...

Comment: You will need to type `grub` in terminal and then hit tab a few times.  You're looking for `grub-efi-install` or `grub2-install` or something ending in -install.

Comment: Will I need to enter the rest of the code after -install from the first terminal command you gave me?

Comment: No, scratch the looking for a command.  Just run `sudo apt-get install grub-efi`

Comment: I tried the second terminal command, no go.  The only -install I can find when searching for grub in the terminal is a plain old grub-install.  I'll try it another time and see what I get.

Comment: Ran sudo apt-get install grub-efi a second time, output said "grub-efi is already the newest version."

Comment: When I installed, I did not create a blank partition for Ubuntu to overwrite.  Could this be my problem?

Comment: perhaps.  Just delete all partitions first, then do a fresh install

Comment: I have to log out for tonight.   Thanks for all of your help, Daniel.  I will try a fresh partition and install tomorrow.