# GRUB menu not showing with dual-boot UEFI mode installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, gpt, mbr

Previously I had Dell Inspiron Laptop with Legacy Boot and MBR disk partitioning with pre-installed Ubuntu 12.04. I needed dual boot with Windows. So I formatted it completely using Live USB, installed new Windows 8.1 and then installed Ubuntu 14.04, each of Windows and Ubuntu in Legacy mode. When I used to start my laptop, after exiting BIOS it shows GRUB menu where I can choose from `Ubuntu` or `Windows 8.1` options.

Now I have HP Pavilion 15 Laptop which has pre-installed windows 8.1 in UEFI mode and GPT disk partitioning. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside on it and everything is working fine except that I had to pres `Esc` key as soon as the laptop starts and then pressing `F9 - Boot Device Options` and then selecting `Ubuntu` from the menu that appeared. If I don't press `F9` it'll directly boot to windows. And no GRUB menu is shown. 
Can someone help me how can I get GRUB menu on it?

Comment: Sounds like you installed Ubuntu in CSM/BIOS/Legacy boot mode not UEFI. UEFI & CSM are not compatible, and you can only select to boot from UEFI or one time boot key, not grub menu. Or grub can only boot systems installed in same boot mode. Also HP is not UEFI boot of Ubuntu friendly. It only boots Windows, but we have work arounds: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and: https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair

Answer (score 8):

First try to change the boot order in **BIOS (UEFI) settings**.
Select Ubuntu to be the default operating system to boot.

If this is not possible boot into Windows and **disable hibernation** and **Fast Boot**.

To disable hibernation open **command prompt as administrator** and execute this command:

```
powercfg /h off
```

To disable Fast Boot open **Control Panel** (the old version - not the modern design),
select the **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and **uncheck Fast Boot**.

After having done this **shutdown** the machine **completely** - do **NOT reboot**!

Then reinstall the GRUB boot loader to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode**.

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media - then  open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd*** /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sd*
update-grub
```

Now you can choose which operating system you want to boot from the GRUB boot loader menu.

Note :

`sd*` = disk | `sd**` = efi partition | `sd***` = system partition

To identify the partition numbers use **GParted**.
The tool is included in the Ubuntu install media.

Answer (score 7):

get in to UEFI setup and change the UEFI boot order.
[image]

you will see a entry like " OS boot Manager"
make it the first entry of the list and save changes.
now it will directly boot in to grub!

Comment: This is not possible, since "ubuntu *" does not show up.  Only OS boot Manager.

Comment: On my HP, that "OS boot Manager" had some sub-options itself. If that's your case, you can change the order of the options there following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/757426/53503).

Answer (score 4):

This applies to most Acer models (Problems generally faced with Predator and other gaming laptops):

For normal Ubuntu installation:

1. Update to the latest BIOS (I know, it's UEFI, but I'm going to call it a BIOS).
2. Shut down, then while starting back up hit the <kbd>F2</kbd> button many times until the BIOS Setup Utility loads.
3. In the "Main" menu, set the "***F12 Boot Menu***" option to "***Enabled***". Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to **Save** and **Exit**, then once Windows loads shut down again.
4. Insert your USB flash drive with your 64-bit Ubuntu installer on it.
5. Power on and keep pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> until the boot menu pops up. Select the flash drive, boot, and install Ubuntu.

**This is where things get tricky**

6. After Ubuntu reboots, it will boot back into Windows. Shut down again. Reboot and hit <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter the BIOS again.
7. Under "***Security***", choose "***Set Supervisor Password***", and set one. You will need this password any time you go back into the BIOS. A bunch of options on the page should change from grey to blue.
8. The "***Select a UEFI file as trusted for executing***" should now be available. If it's not available, check that Secure Boot is still enabled, if not, enable it. Select it, and navigate to **HDD0->EFI->ubuntu->grubx64.efi**. The BIOS will ask you for a name for it, I called it Grub.
9. Hit <kbd>F10</kbd> to save and exit, then immediately hit <kbd>F2</kbd> again to re-enter the BIOS.
10. Now go to "***Boot***", set "***Secure Boot***" to "***Disabled***", and arrow down to the bottom of the list to your new "***Grub***" entry. Hit <kbd>F6</kbd> until it's the top of the list.
11. Hit <kbd>F10</kbd> one last time. Your system should now reboot to the Grub boot loader!

Credits- [[HOW-TO] Dual boot Acer Aspire R14 - Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the following work on a Lenovo Ideapad 120S with Lubuntu 20.04:

1. During boot up enter BIOS by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> on.
2. Go to *Boot* menu → *Boot mode* and select *Legacy Support* (instead of *UEFI*).

Then the GRUB menu should appear on reboot without having to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or any other key.

Answer (score 0):

I have an HP 11 laptop and also have the same issue. Every time it boots up it shows the HP logo and then goes into Windows 10.

The easiest way to overcome this is to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> during startup, or press <kbd>F9</kbd> to directly select the OS. Then you can choose *Windows* or *Ubuntu*.

Comment: I struggled a lot with my HP, too, was almost getting used to press <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> for the rest of my life... But [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/757426/53503) saved my day. Its summary: use the right keys to move the OS Boot Manager's order!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because the boot order got changed on its own.
The steps which I followed to fix it were:

1. Boot into Windows, search for "advanced startup" and open the Settings app, and click Restart
2. Now, find your way to the UEFI firmware settings, this is different for different brands
3. Once you're in, find the boot options tab and see the boot order menu
4. It will have something called the "OS Boot Manager" with a right arrow pointing to it
5. Highlight this and press enter
6. Press F5/F6 to put Ubuntu above Windows Boot Manager
7. Press F10 to save the changes
8. Save all your changes and exit the UEFI settings

It should show Grub now