# Grub Isn't Showing Up After Dual Boot Windows Installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I know there are multiple questions on the site that have already asked this question, and those solutions have worked every other time I've dual booted Windows and Linux (this is my 5th time and I always have this problem). However, unlike every other time I've done this, no solution seems to be working. Basically, every time I boot up my computer, GRUB doesn't show and I boot straight to Windows. I have no idea as to how I can even get into my Linux installation. Here are the things I've tried:

Running `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

Running `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shim.efi`

Running `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`

Disabling Hibernation and Fastboot

Running Boot Repair (this completed but it threw an error. [Here](https://pastebin.com/UZnggdba) is the pastebin)

Running `sudo update-grub` (fails)

Running `sudo grub-install` (fails)

Trying everything mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/681422/grub-menu-not-showing-with-dual-boot-uefi-mode-installation) (fails)

Also, the only options in the BIOS for boot order are HDD, External HDD, USB, and Network (No ubuntu, OS loader, or Windows options)

I'm really not sure what to do here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: according to your Boot Repair post, grub isn't installed. did you boot the installer in EFI mode?

Comment: @ravery How do I do that? If you mean UEFI, my BIOS is set to boot as UEFI.

Comment: is legacy boot disabled?? many systems will drop to Legacy boot if the boot media can boot legacy mode (which the ubuntu installer can )

Comment: @ravery Should be. In the BIOS there's a dropdown that allows you to select from UEFI or Legacy. In mine, UEFI is selected. I'm not sure whether it's falling back on legacy, though. There's no setting that would indicate that, but my BIOS is particularly sparse.

Comment: is this a fresh install? it would probably be best to start from scratch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grub not showing on startup for Windows 8.1 Ubuntu 13.10 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem. You should install windows first on your PC and then try to install Ubuntu, It works and you can access both the OS without problem