# Ubuntu Desktop 18.10 UEFI grub not booting

Tags: uefi, grub-efi, 18.10

Neither live CD nor USB image does boot in UEFI on my system. Black screen, that is all, no grub-efi does show up. So, not even coming close to the point to install or reinstall. With 18.04 UEFI ist fine and works as designed.

Comment: Have you (re)installed 18.10? Doing a release upgrade from 18.04 shouldn't have changed the bootloader.

Comment: Was 18.04 install using EFI mode or bios mode?

Comment: Sorry folks, neither live CD nor USB image does boot in UEFI on my system. Black screen, that is all, no grub-efi does show up. So, not even coming close to the point to install or reinstall. With 18.04 UEFI ist fine and works as designed.

Answer (score 1):

**Boot from a live USB**, (or the disk you used to install Ubuntu) the boot device selection in your bios may have multiple options. *choose the UEFI device*

**Identify your boot device** with `sudo fdisk -l` or `gpartid`.

**chroot** into your system. (`/dev/sda` in this example) replace `sda#` with *your device*

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt #sda2 is the root partition
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi #sda1 is the efi partition
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/ #makes the network available after chrooting
modprobe efivars # make sure this is loaded
sudo chroot /mnt
```

**Reinstall and update GRUB**

```
apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64
```

or if you have a 32bit system:

```
apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi
```

then

```
update-grub
```

**exit chroot** with `Ctrl+D`

**unmount everything and reboot**

```
for i in /sys /proc /dev/pts /dev; do sudo umount /mnt$i; done
sudo umount /mnt/boot/efi #please do this. Corrupted efi partitions are not nice
sudo umount /mnt
sudo reboot
```

---

I've referenced these answers:
https://superuser.com/a/376471/953420
https://askubuntu.com/a/681442/234305

Comment: Sorry folks, neither live CD nor USB image does boot in UEFI on my system. Black screen, that is all, no grub-efi does show up. So, not even coming close to the point to install or reinstall. With 18.04 UEFI ist fine and works as designed.