# Ubuntu doesn't appear in the boot order list

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, grub-efi

Last time I had an error installing Ubuntu because when I selected Windows 10 on the grub list, Windows 10 always showed a message saying "Windows 10 needs repair".

But that error happen because I was installing Ubuntu in Legacy, not uefi.

But now I'm having another error installing Ubuntu in dual boot Windows 10 in UEFI. When I go to the UEFI Bios, the Ubuntu hard disk doesn't appear on the list bios boot to change!

My bios mode is UEFI + Legacy.

Does it have anything to do with the bios mode?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you never reach the GRUB menu, since you do not see the partition in the BIOS screen. I am no expert in this domain, but I am assuming it has something to do with the partition mounting. I would first recommend using Legacy bios mode and check if it helps. If not, perhaps [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/681442/669558) in a related thread might be useful.

Comment: Thank you so much @dotdeb. I finally did it!