# GRUB menu does not appear

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios, csm

I have a similar problem like [this previous post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/681422/grub-menu-not-showing-with-dual-boot-uefi-mode-installation).

So, I am using ASUS motherboard desktop. Previously the OS was Windows 10, very probably in UEFI mode, I did not check that, and that was my worst mistake. Recently I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on it as dual boot. The Ubuntu I installed in Lagacy/BIOS mode. After that, I could see both Windows and Ubuntu from the GRUB menu, but only Ubuntu could load, and Windows 10 was not loading (just black screen). I found out that this is because of the two separate modes of these two OSs.

As I could not open Windows 10, I thought it could be a good idea if I changed Ubuntu to UEFI mode. I tried a few google suggestions, finally I tried with BOOT_REPAIR:

- In advanced mode, very probably I select the MBR Disk partitioning and reboot the computer.

However, after that reboot, I now even cannot see the grub menu. It is just a black screen and in the top left corner the cursor blinking. I tried pressing `shift` or `esc` key for some time to bring back the grub menu, but it did not work.

Also tried to change menu `BOOT>> CSM enable/disable`, `Secure boot enable/disable`. It did not work. Moreover, disabling CSM is just reloading the BOOT menu each time I reboot the computer.

The final option I may try to re-install Ubuntu in UEFI mode, but I cannot lose any of these Operating systems at this moment because of the software-configuration and files.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: what exactly did you do? [this question] has a full list of instructions, what did you follow? was your disk MBR or GPT before you did the conversion? Are both OSes on the same drive?

Comment: Windows in UEFI boot mode must be gpt partitioned. If you changed to MBR, you erased drive. The setting for UEFI or old BIOS/CSM/Legacy is for installed system. If Secure boot is off & if you have a setting for USB that is set to allow USB boot, then you must have a Ubuntu installer that is for UEFI installs. And then UEFI will show UEFI:xxxx where xxxx is name or label of flash drive. Most tools to create installer will make it UEFI, but a few will make an old BIOS installer for old systems, so you have to choose correctly when making Ubuntu live installer flash drive.

Comment: @Esther the instructions are the thing I did.

Comment: @oldfred, thanks a lot. I knew the secure boot option and it worked fine on my laptop, but the desktop boot menu, I could not turn it off, I could disable CSM so far, but then it created another issue. In short, previous Ubuntu was in Privacy mode, now installing fresh copy in UEFI mode.