# How to boot into Ubuntu or Windows

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I have installed [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) along with Windows 8.1. When I turn on the computer I don't get an option to boot into Ubuntu, and I go strait into Windows. How can I solve this?

I have tried using boot-repair, but I could not install it on live Ubuntu (as the Internet connection is not working), so it is working in my 'installed' version of Ubuntu. There I am not able to use the 'recommended repair' option.

Here is my pastebin link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15306542/

Comment: Looks like you simply have to install the GRUB boot loader to `/dev/sda`. Probably you selected something else in the installer (probably `/dev/sda7`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: You have an HP, which violates UEFI spec and uses description to boot. You need to create /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi that really is shimx64.efi and boot hard drive or fallback entry in UEFI. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual boot Win 8 / Ubuntu loads only Win](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win)

Answer (score 1):

1. **Disable hibernation and fast startup in Windows.**

   - Open command prompt as administrator and execute:

     ```
     powercfg /h off
     ```
   - Open Windows Control Panel.
   - Go to *Power Settings*.
   - Uncheck *Fast startup*.
2. **Shutdown the machine completely - do NOT reboot.**
3. **Reinstall GRUB boot loader for Ubuntu in EFI mode.**

   - Boot from the Ubuntu installation medium.
   - Select *Try Ubuntu without installing*.
   - Open a terminal and execute:

     ```
     sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
     sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot/efi
     for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
     sudo chroot /mnt
     grub-install /dev/sda
     update-grub
     ```

   Note:

   `sda` = disk | `sda2` = EFI partition | `sda7` = system partition
4. **Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu as default system.**