# Ubuntu won't boot from my hard drive, only a trial version from USB-Live pendrive

Tags: boot, 15.10, toshiba-satellite, toshiba

I've tried to google my problem before registering here and I did find a lot of people having similar issues that I have but never actually found a solution that would work for me.

Basically speaking I bought one of those laptops with Windows 10 sticker, installed Ubuntu 15.10 on it (formatting the whole disk) from USB-Live. Everything went smooth, however after installation I am not able to boot my computer from my hard drive anymore. It automatically boots from my USB-Live pendrive even though the priority of booting is set to hard drive as first & the secure booting is disabled. When I remove the pendrive I get black screen.

Laptop model: Toshiba Satellite C55D

Comment: Laptop model would be helpful.

Comment: Toshiba Satellite C55D

Comment: Do you have Secure Boot turned off in the BIOS?

Comment: And 15.04 is no longer supported. You should consider installing a current release, such as 14.04 or 15.10

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my post: "& the secure booting is disabled."
And it is in fact 15.10, I just messed up on the tag (after writing down "15" the automatic suggestion is "15.04" that's why I clicked it without too much thinking) - I fixed my tag :)

Comment: Some possibly similar Toshiba: https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair General info: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=broadwell-lap-winlin&num=1 And: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2267408

Answer (score 1):

Well, take out the usb for starters.  Next is make sure you have the trusted boot file added to your bios in your computer.  I bet this is your first uefi laptop.  I keep telling people to post a bug on ubuntu for not telling people they need to do this on the install.

I searched and it seems to say you need to change to cms mode in advanced options.

You could also try boot-repair.

When all else fails, change to legacy boot and reinstall.
You need to make a usb with live linux creator or universal usb installer for legacy.  This is broken until 16.04 gets active again with a new startup disk creator.

I have had both methods work in my acer laptop and settled on legacy.
After the bios update, it was forgetting my trusted boot files that I was setting.  I dropped back down to the older bios and then went legacy for both win 10 and lubuntu.

Do not get confused between two problems.  Usb legacy boot problem and uefi.  You need to activate uefi to find the secure boot settings to add the trusted source.  You also need to set a password to see that option.  Be very careful when setting a bios password.   Be sure to reset it back to nothing by setting password again and hitting《enter》.. (nothing).  If you forget the bios password, you have big problems so set it back to nothing once you are fished adding the trusted source.

Again.  I recommend legacy.  So..
Make a proper new usb installer.
Switch to legacy boot.
Install.
Finished.

I needed to change the partition to mbr in order to install windows as legacy.  Not a big problem unless your are over 2 to (I think).  You are limited to 4 paritions too.  (Almost a problem for me)..but I only have 32gb anyway.

Comment: Could you be more specific, please? "make sure you have the trusted boot file added to your bios in your computer" - what do you mean and how do I do that? After I changed to CMS I get the black screen with the following message: error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found - entering rescue mode... and I can't do anything about it. I get the same whenever I try to start from hard drive or USB-Live. Had to change back to UEFI in order to be able to use my USB-Live trial version of Ubuntu on this computer.

Comment: Universal usb installer or live linux installer are usb legacy compatible usb makers.  Ubuntu won't fix this until 16.04 startup disk creator.  Go to bios and fumble around about adding trusted sources to your boot.  Like try security heading.  For me I had to create a password,  and then more options opened up.  You must have uefi boot active to see these options.  My bios then says "select an uefi file as trusted for executing".  There you can   Then (important), clear the password by resetting the password to (empty).  This was for my acer.  Lastly try boot repair.