# Unable to dual boot windows 8.1 with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I m new to this forum and to linux.  I have windows 8.1 pre-installed in my HP 15-r007tx and I wanna make it dual boot with ubuntu. But last I tried I finished installing ubuntu based on a few videos on youtube but here is the deal. When I restart I dont get the grub bootloader. My system boots with windows directly. Someone please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in BIOS or UEFI boot mode? How you boot install media is how it installs. Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question, in order to boot to your "second" OS, whenever the computer initially starts up you need to go to your boot menu, I've never had a computer that automatically went to the boot menu so you have to ask it do that.

When your computer starts up it should have a message on the screen indicating which F-key it is to go to your boot menu. F12 is a pretty common one I believe.
After you get into the boot menu select the hard drive your OS is on and then a list of the available OSes should come up, select the one you want and you should be good to go.

Comment: Actually from what I saw GRUB is supposed to load automatically which lets me choose between windows 8.1 and Ubuntu. But what is happening is I have to manually boot by pressing f9 and choosing the ubuntu OS boot