# Can I permanently stop Windows over-riding my efibootmgr settings after entering BIOS?

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10, efibootmgr

I have a dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu HP Laptop.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 I had a lot of little issues and decided to do a clean install.  This coincided with wanting to upgrade to 10 and so I followed this guide - [How can I dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on a UEFI HP notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook)

To be honest, that's the best guide I've ever seen and it worked with no issues.  I used efibootmgr to get my boot order correct and it's been working great.

The problem I have is that I wanted to try and get Nvidia drivers working correctly.  It seems that a lot of people have issues with them, and one of the fixes involved insuring secure boot was off.  I went into my BIOS and then as soon as I restarted, Windows booted immediately.

I fixed this issue by manually changing my bootorder and then reconfiguring efibootmgr.

Is there a permanent way to stop this happening?  I'm suspecting it's something to do with the way Windows works and writes to the boot drive.  Whilst it's not a major issue as I know how to fix it I don't want to have to do this everytime I go into BIOS for anything.

Thanks, Chopper

Comment: Is Windows' FastBoot off? Also, you could just let the BIOS/UEFI load Windows' Boot Manager and configure that one (using bcdedit) to boot GRUB instead of Windows. That's how I did it...

Comment: Many with HP, have to use the Hard Drive boot entry which is /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. That is a default or fallback UEFI boot entry that seems to still work when /EFI/ubuntu will not. Normally Windows makes bootx64.efi a copy of the Windows efi file, but we change that to shimx64.efi. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and/or: https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair Or edit Widnows BCD or use rEFInd (both in first link).

Comment: I left my laptop at work but I'll definitely try these tomorrow and let you know how I get on