# Why Do I Keep Getting GRUB Command Line on Startup - Dual Booting Wins 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

I migrated data on my laptop's HDD which contains Windows 8.1 to my SSD and replaced the HDD with the SSD (My laptop has 2 hard drive bays btw). Currently, my Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 are on their own SDDs. Before this, I was able to boot straight into the GRUB OS selection screen where I could select to boot into Windows 8.1 or Ubuntu 14.04. But now, every time I start my laptop, I get this screen

[image]

Once I type `exit` into that command line. I get this screen (btw, I have reconfigured to remove the duplicate entry for Ubuntu after I took this screenshot)
[image]

After selecting `ubuntu` I am able to see the OS selection screen.
[image]

Also, when I am in Ubuntu, and restart, it boots directly into Windows without showing the GRUB command line screen. My question is, how can I boot straight to GRUB OS selection screen on startup?

The current boot order entries.
[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: check this may help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot?rq=1

Comment: @MohamedSlama Thank you for your comment. I've tried those solutions. did not help.

Comment: Your boot order is messed up. Typing `sudo efibootmgr -v` in an Ubuntu Terminal will show you the details. Pay attention to the `BootOrder` line, and review the various options. You may be able to figure out an appropriate boot order and set it with the `-o` option to `efibootmgr`. If not, post the output of `sudo efibootmgr -v`. (Edit your question and post the output, adding four spaces to the start of every line to keep the forum from mangling the formatting.)

Comment: @RodSmith Thank you for your input. I've added the screenshot of the output. I removed Windows Boot Manager using EasyUEFI, that's why the line for Boot0001 above is not marked with an asterisk. I still get the grub command line screen however,  but it won't boot straight into Windows anymore when I start my laptop after shutting off for a long time, which is great. But I would love for it to boot to the grub OS selection screen directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this from an Ubuntu Terminal Window:

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0
```

That should fix the problem. Alternatively, you could use EasyUEFI in Windows to move the `ubuntu` entry to the top of the boot order list.

---

**EDIT:**

If it's resetting to boot straight to Windows when you reboot the computer *without* booting into Windows, then your EFI is badly broken. Check the manufacturer's site for an update (probably called a "BIOS upgrade" or something similar). If that doesn't help, then the best course of action is to return the computer for a refund, assuming you're within the return period. If not, you'll need to employ an ugly hack involving renaming boot loader files. Boot Repair can do this semi-automatically with an option on its Advanced menu, or you can do it manually, as noted [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/installation.html#alternative-naming) Either way, if it's a bad EFI, ***write to the manufacturer to complain!*** Too many have been delivering junk EFIs for too long!

If this happens only after booting to Windows, then chances are Windows is the culprit. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager) covers this variant of the problem.

Comment: Hi Rod, it still doesn't help, it won't still boot the grub OS selection screen. I even tried to explicitly set the boot order using this command `sudo efibootmgr -o 0000,0001,3001,0003,2001,2002`, but when I restart my laptop. It still falls back to this order `0001,3001,0000,0003,2001,2002` with the bootnum for `ubuntu` being pushed to the third. I've also tried setting the boot order and removing the entry for Windows Boot Manger, but when I restart my laptop. Windows Boot Manager still takes precedence over everybody else. I think I am ok right now since it doesn't boot to Windows at least

Comment: Please see my edit, above.

Comment: You show several hard drive entries. Do not know if UEFI or BIOS. But UEFI hard drive boots /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which normally is a copy of Windows efi boot file. You can make that shimx64.efi and using hard drive UEFI boot to boot grub/Ubuntu. Boot-Repair auto copies shim with  'Use the standard EFI file' in advanced options. Or other HP: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and: https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair