# Two instances of grub

Tags: grub2, grub-efi

I tried installing Ubuntu on my laptop several times and finally succeeded(dual boot)
I need to select ubuntu from boot menu in order to open grub and start ubuntu
So that is not my problem
My actual problem is:

> 1. i see two ubuntu written on the menu
> 2. Is this two instances of grub
> 3. My ubuntu also runs very slow Is it due to this two instances of grub

How can I remove one of them ?

My Laptop is Hp pavilion g6 2320tx
Intel core i5 
4GB RAM
1 TB hdd
Graphic processor amd mobility radeon 7670M
(i have disabled the radeon graphics in linux just to check whether this is causing the laptop getting slow but no change detect , still slow , the radeon graphics is still disabled)

**EDIT 1**
The result of

```
sudo update-grub
```

[image: screenshot]

The result of

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
```

[image: efibootmgr]

Comment: Do you see anything in bracket after Ubuntu in GRUB menu like `Ubuntu (On /dev/Sda3)`?

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `sudo update-grub`

Comment: With UEFI install you get both shimx64.efi & grubx64.efi. To see details: `sudo efibootmgr -v` What laptop brand/model? Or specs. Should not be slow, not related to grub.

Comment: @7_R3X i can see an /dev/sda2 with a label of windows boot loader

Comment: @7_R3X i have added the result of sudo update-grub

Comment: @oldfred i have added the result of sudo efibootmgr -v and also updated my laptop's specification

Comment: Better to just post text (formatted) than screen shots. With HP you may want to make the Internal Hard disk entry really boot shimx64.efi. Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair

Answer (score 1):

Your screen shots aren't showing up for me. In general, multiple entries in the EFI's boot menu should not be a problem. In fact, it's common to see two such entries, one pointing to `grubx64.efi` and the other to `shimx64.efi`. If this is what you're seeing, it's perfectly normal. I wouldn't worry about this or attempt to "fix" it unless you think it's causing a real problem. I say this because mucking with these entries can cause much more serious problems, like a complete failure to boot; it's just not worth it to fix a minor cosmetic issue. That said....

I recommend you look at the `BootOrder` item in the `efibootmgr -v` output. Chances are it's set incorrectly, and setting it to boot one of the `ubuntu` entries (either one if you're not using Secure Boot, or the one pointing to `shimx64.efi` if you are) will get the system booting directly into GRUB. You can do this via the `-o` option to `efibootmgr`, as in `sudo efibootmgr -o 0002,0000,0003` to boot `Boot0002` as a first priority, `Boot0000` if that fails, and `Boot0003` if neither of the preceding options works. You must check your actual `efibootmgr -v` output to figure out what order to use, of course. Alternatively, you could do this using [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) in Windows.

Multiple EFI boot manager entries should *not* cause speed problems in Ubuntu. I recommend you post a new question about that topic. Chances are you've got a runaway process, too little RAM, or some other problem that's completely unrelated to EFI or GRUB. Typing `top` in a window will show details that might be helpful, so posting a screen shot of that may be worthwhile -- but please be sure you post the screen shot correctly.

Comment: I have tried typing top also

Comment: Nothing is taking up my ram or CPU usage ,still it's slow when I open Facebook or YouTube or watch videos online

Comment: It's not a problem with browser or flash as I have already tried other browsers too, they also had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This is standard for ubuntu and for that matter most other linux distributions when the kernel is updated the package manager retains one previous version and removes the older ones. This is done for a reason, if there is some issue with the new kernel install it lets you boot the system with the previous known good kernel instead.

Of course there is no real reason to keep it after you are sure that the newer kernel boots correctly in your case you could use the following command to remove the older 4.4.0-21 kernel installation:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-*-4.4.0-21
```

There is really no need to do this however unless you are in the situation where a few tens of megabytes of disk space is critical in which case honestly it's probably advisable to consider investing in a hardware upgrade since a few hundred megabytes is hardly any space and you would constantly be running into the need to remove things as the disk fills up every 5 minutes.

Comment: My laptop while using ubuntu is quite slow and lags alot, i cant even properly open a window because it takes quite a time to do it , is this because of this dual file ?, do you recommend me to remove it?,will it effect my windows 8 ?

Comment: The OP's issue has nothing to do with multiple kernel installations; it has to do with multiple `ubuntu` entries in the EFI.