# How to boot to grub by default?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

My laptop normally shows the GRUB boot menu with options to boot to Ubuntu or with windows boot manager. I pressed escape by accident and then typed in exit in the GRUB command line. Then I pressed esc as instructed in the EFI to shut down. After restarting my laptop, it took me straight to windows 8. Now I can't get to GRUB when I start up my hardware.

I tried booting with my Ubuntu CD but there doesn't seem to be any repair option.

How do I make GRUB appear by default again?

EDIT:
I was able to access GRUB through the UEFI boot options, but it still doesn't appear by default. I have to get to the UEFI through windows settings every time.

Comment: What brand, model system. You can try this: Change boot order with efibootmgr, some require all 4 hex char others 1 is ok.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr example: `sudo efibootmgr -o 2,1` But some brands only boot Windows entry first, work around is to make grub be a fallback or hard drive entry that can be also first: Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair

Comment: I tried efibootmgr and changed the boot order. But sure enough, it made no difference. I checked the boot order after rebooting and it seems my changes had been reversed.

Comment: I'm using an HP Pavilion 15 that came with windows 8. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside it recently and had no problems - Ubuntu would be the default OS, but not since I exited GRUB from the command line interface (which I thought would simply shut down the system).

Comment: Is there any way I can reconfigure the BIOS/EFI. I tried to change the boot order from the "BIOS setup" (F10), but 'OS boot manager' was the only option apart from Network and Hard Drive/SSD, no 'ubuntu'? Something that doesn't require moving the efi file?

Comment: When you copy shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi or have Boot-Repair automatically do that, you then have to boot UEFI:hard drive or similar entry. If one does not exist, then you may have to create it. And you should be able to make the fallback/hard drive entry first in boot order. But ubuntu entry with HP does not normally work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out accessing EFI on "Windows 8 hardware" car reorder the boot sequence. I solved my problem by reinstalling Windows 8 (settings > general > re-install windows) and then Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

That's unfortunate pal.. Looks like Ubuntu's bootloader has been removed from the Master boot record. You can try this out

- Disable Fast Startup, and shut down your computer then boot up again.
- Try booting using a Live CD and go to Terminal & reinstall grub for your drive in this way from the Live CD `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` where X is the letter of your drive.
- Alternatively check this [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) or [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2) or [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook) out.
- If all fail, perhaps you can create a thread on this [forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/newthread.php?do=newthread&f=333)

Best of luck pal.

Comment: Tried reinstalling grub, but it didn't help :(

Comment: Did you update grub? as in `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Yes, from both a regular session as well as a LiveCD session