# UEFI: Installing Ubuntu along with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I want Ubuntu to run as second OS on my Laptop which has Windows 10 preinstalled. I had a Kubuntu version running but unfortunately Windows 10 was installed with UEFI while I installed the Kubuntu in lagacy BIOS. 
That worked but it was quite anoying to switch operating systems (also Kubuntu had huge problems with my touchpad). So I installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode on the partitions the Kubuntu was once installed on. I expected my laptop to let my choose between Windows and Ubuntu the next time I restart but Windows starts automatically. 

The installation was without errors and Windows quickstart is disabled. What can I do to make the Windows Bootmanager recognize Ubuntu?

---

I have an Acer Aspire V5-591G-54PC

Comment: Normally you do not use Windows to boot Ubuntu/grub. But a few do add a entry to BCD as that is the only way the hardware works. That uses UEFI one time boot, so you boot into Windows, then reboot into UEFI and UEFI loads grub entry in UEFI. What brand/model laptop. Some just need to have ubuntu entry moved to first in boot order, some need other work arounds. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair

Comment: I just use the Windows Boot Loader because it is already there and Ubuntu did not install anything else. I thought that Ubuntu knows what it does when I install it

Comment: Windows boot loader is not designed for multi-boot systems, other than perhaps Windows. Grub is designed to boot multiple systems. Many vendors "lock" system to only boot Windows, by using description as part of UEFI boot. That also is a violation of UEFI standard, but since many vendors now do that, it must be suggested by Microsoft.

Comment: might running boot repair solve my problem?

Comment: If an Acer and UEFI you need to set a supervisory password in UEFI and enable trust on ubuntu or grub's .efi boot files in ESP. http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot and: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742

Comment: now I can change the boot device, but all I get is a console and ubuntu still does not start

Comment: What video card chip. How much RAM? If nVidia you may need nomodeset boot parameter until you install proprietary driver from Ubuntu's repository. At grub menu you can use e for edit, scroll to linux line and replace quiet splash with nomodeset.
How to set NOMODESET and other kernel boot options in grub2 - both BIOS liveCD & grub first boot ( also UEFI with grub) 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132 and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing Ubuntu with the automatic option to install it alongside Windows. After following the steps provided with [Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot) and setting the grub loader as first boot devices I was able to switch between the operating systems. Sadly it did not leave me with the option to install Ubuntu on the partitions I want and I have it running un my HDD only