# Ubuntu does not boot after installation (Alongside windows 8)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, ubuntu-gnome

I installed Ubuntu GNOME on my HP Probook 650 G1. I did this as follows:

- Disabled secureboot
- Disabled fastboot in w8
- Created free space using the windows partition manager
- Opened up the Ubuntu live environment
- Created a swap partition and a main partition to mount /
- Run the installer

When this was done my laptop booted in windows 8. I can enter Ubuntu via boot options (from UEFI).

I tried:

- Checking if I really disabled secureboot and fastboot
- Running boot-repair
- Changing boot order (ubuntu was not listed but falls under 'OS manager' which boots windows)

Can I try something else? Ubuntu had been working before on this laptop with no troubles. When the installation broke, I completely wiped the disk and reinstalled Windows. Now this.

Comment: HP uses description as part of UEFI boot. And only valid description is "Windows Boot Manager". So a work around is required, usually using the hard drive or fallback entry. Boot-Repair now copies shimx64.efi to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which is the hard drive boot, but does not add the UEFI entry. Your HP may already have that, or it can be added with efibootmgr. Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and
https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair

Comment: Have you tried enabling "Backup and rename Windows EFI files" (under main options) in `boot-repair`'s advanced options?

Comment: U didnt give home partition with swap and /(root)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the technique described by the two links olfred posted. And after that running boot-repair again with "Backup and rename Windows EFI files" as suggested by insert_name_here.

**How I did it:**

- Followed the instructions from this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair).
- Ran boot repair with the "Backup and rename Windows EFI files" option.

**Explanation**

I first tried to overwrite the original efi files with that of ubuntu's (and GRUB) that caused my machine not to boot anymore. The manufacturers lock had to be overridden. That's when the extra option in boot-repair came in.

Thanks to all for helping.