# No second operating system available and no boot menu available (only Windows 8.1 starts and is visible in WIN-Boot-Menu)

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have no boot-menu after installing UBUNTU 16 on SAME HD (separate partition) than Windows 8.1 
I have a HP ENVY DV7 Laptop with Windows 8.1RT, on which I try to install and boot UBUNTU 16
Can anyone tell me what to doä?
Tks a lot,

Comment: HP almost always requires a work around: Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789
https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair  Boot-Repair now creates  bkpbootx64.efi and copies shimx64.efi as bootx64.efi. This is a hard drive default or fallback boot entry in UEFI.
 'Use the standard EFI file' in advanced options.
You may still have to add a UEFI boot entry to use that. Some UEFI auto find the hard drive boot entry.

Comment: Will you run this command and update your question with the output?  `lsblk;sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many things and I think HP does not want to allow dual boot on my machine and others like it.  My HP 15 (not Envy) started with Windows 8.1 but was first upgraded with the Windows 10 "free" version and now the anniversary version.  All had the same issue- no boot menu (with dual boot option) at startup.  The workaround I found is long and not convenient.  Go to SETTINGS/UPDATE AND SECURITY/RECOVERY/ADVANCED STARTUP (needs to restart)/USE A DEVICE/UBUNTU.  Then, the traditional dual boot screen appears (default is Ubuntu).  It is a long way around.  I had read of the boot repair option mentioned earlier but was reluctant to go that route.

Good luck