# Grub2 installed on Legacy thus EFI windows boots directly

Tags: dual-boot, grub-efi, grub-legacy

I have windows 7 installed on EFI, I installed Ubuntu on legacy as Windows had secure boot on and I had a message which asked to install Ubumtu on legacy instead of EFI. Now when I boot the laptop, windows starys automatically, if I want to acccess Ubumtu, I have to emter bios and select booting from ubuntu grub(2 are listed for some reason), when the menu appears, an option to boot into either Ubuntu or Win7 is shown.

How do I solve this problem to get the grub showing at boot?

Here is a link to Bootinfo Summary:
http://paste2.org/9kwD8mf8

Comment: Windows 7 does not support UEFI Secure Boot. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @oldfres done, I editted the original text with a link to pastebin.

Comment: Your installs are all UEFI. But you booted Boot-Repair in BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot mode. Best to boot in UEFI mode all the time including all repair flash drives/installers. Report does not show all UEFI boot entries. Do you have ubuntu, Windows and an UEFI hard drive entry? What brand/model system? Some brands need specific work arounds.

Comment: It's an HP, I tried installing Ubuntu on EFI but it said it might cause deletion of my Windows. That's why I used the non EFI installation.

Comment: You have Ubuntu installed in UEFI boot mode. But HP are not dual boot friendly. Many work arounds. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and: https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair and: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2332681&p=13527216#post13527216

Comment: You can probably fix it with EasyUEFI or `bcdedit` in Windows. See [this question and its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager/683657) for details.

Answer (score -1):

Disable secureboot from BIOS settings and then clean install Ubuntu on EFI. 
Don't forget to turn secureboot on back. Worked on my machine.