# Dual Boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-10

I install Windows 10 and after allocating partition for Ubuntu I also installed Ubuntu 16.04. but when machine boot on it only boots Windows it didnt show option to chose Ubuntu or Windows 10 .how to fix this....Please Help me

Comment: Have you changed the boot order in the BIOS?

Comment: @TonyLancer OP's on a single drive, so that shouldn't matter. But I think he needs to disable fastboot and possibly even reinstall `grub`.

Comment: @PatrickNegus Sometimes when Ubuntu installs, it doesn't change the boot order, so Windows boots up again.  I believe he has to install [boot repair](http://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc) to get it working.

Comment: What brand/model computer. Some just need settings in UEFI to change boot order, some like Acer need special "trust" settings, and some need work arounds as they use description to boot and only valid description is "Windows Boot Manager". Work arounds; http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and: https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried booting Ubuntu through BIOS, before Win10 boots?
If that works, maybe just change the boot cycle so that Ubuntu is booted first.