# Ubuntu 18.04/16.04 boot problem

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have a problem booting into Ubuntu 18.04. Before this I had Ubuntu 16.04, then I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and got this error.

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\Boot\mmx64.efi: Not Found
Failed to start MokManager: Not Found
System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.
Create boot entry "Boot0000" with label "ubuntu" for file "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64"

Reset System
```

Then I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 back and got the same error. After that I freed my disk (by setting all disk space to zero, formatting) and reinstalled Ubuntu, but I got the same error. Afterwards I installed Boot-Repair and reinstalled  grub, but nothing changed. I have a Sony VAIO SVP112A1CV notebook. GPT was made by Rufus and tried it by running the `dd` command in Linux.

Comment: Boot-Repair should have copied shimx64.efi to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which is the fallback or hard drive boot entry. Sony violates UEFI spec that says NOT to use description as part of boot. Other work around if not dual booting with Windows is to create a "Windows Boot Manager" entry that really boots shimx64.efi. Sony, HP & others workarounds:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair

Answer (score 0):

Did you try restarting the computer or removing the system battery, that is all i can think because i had a similar error with ubuntu 14.04 and i removed the system battery and restarted the computer and it booted

if that doesn't work try booting ubuntu on another pc or use a different hard disk (if it isn't then that might be the problem)