I have a problem with installing Ubuntu on Toshiba satellite
what i should doWhen it says how to install Ubuntu it doesn’t show anything.

question is flawed: you don't uninstall an OS, You install an OS. See the instructions on how to install the OS you want. If you want to remove the OS and replace it with anything else than Ubuntu you are asking the wrong crowd; askUbuntu is for Ubuntu

When it says how to install Ubuntu it doesn’t show anything what should I do? This is confusing. What have you tried? Please edit the question and add more details.

What have you tried - and how did it fail ?

Did you try the next button? 24.04 install from the background. You should eventually select a device and a partition for root.

What model Toshiba? UEFI install? Some require you to change drive to AHCI from RAID and if using Windows add AHCI drivers to WIndows for it to keep working. Or it could be Windows settings for fast startup or hibernation. New Toshibas are now Dynabooks. https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair

I am using Toshiba satellite c50 -b-15g

Additionally, it's not asking HOW, though it may see that way, it's asking WHERE. You need a raw or otherwise unallocated partition or other disk device available for the installation of Ubuntu. The installer is not seeing this so it wants either a) a partition from the single disk in the computer, OR, it wants you to specify a disk other than the  boot disk if it exists.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
